VBA Chart creation
I am trying to set up a script to create vertical stacked bar charts from compiled data but I can't get it to work, graphs/charts are the bane of my excel life..
The data is in a range 4 columns wide and variable no. of rows, I have been determining the no. of entries by counting up and storing number as variable drlr, I have also set variables for the columns as charts will be made for up to 30 data sets. The first column should contain the horizontal x-axis labels and there will be a separate bar for each row of the table. The series names should be the title line of each column and the data will be in range(501,col2) to (drlr, col4). Each column will have a colour assigned denoting the role in the title line with the legend showing this and the formatting should be consistent across all charts.
If anyone can help with this it would be greatly appreciated, my eyes are falling out and I think I am getting further from the solution the more I try to fix it.
Here is the code, it's a mess.. I think at the moment the data is offset between charts somehow.
Sub CreateStackedBarChart()
Dim wsLookup As Worksheet
Dim wsAvail As Worksheet
Dim engRange As Range
Dim engCell As Range
Dim chartObj As ChartObject
Dim chartTitle As String
Dim seriesNamesRange As Range
Dim seriesValuesRange As Range
Dim seriesColors As Variant
Dim p As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, drlr As Long
Dim lastChartTop As Long
Dim w As Long

' Set reference to the Availability and Lookup worksheets
Set wsAvail = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Availability")
Set wsLookup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lookup")

' Set range for engineer names
Set engRange = wsLookup.Range("C6:C36")

' Initial column indices
p = 18
j = 19
k = 20
l = 21

' Define series colors
seriesColors = Array(RGB(0, 59, 92), RGB(0, 174, 214), RGB(0, 230, 210))

' Initialize the top position for the first chart
lastChartTop = 100

' Loop through each engineer
For Each engCell In engRange
    ' Set chart title
    chartTitle = engCell.Value
    
    drlr = wsLookup.Cells(wsLookup.Rows.Count, p).End(xlUp).row

   
    ' Create a new chart object
    Set chartObj = wsAvail.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=1000, Top:=lastChartTop, Height:=700)
    
    ' Set chart type to stacked bar
    chartObj.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    
    ' Set chart title
    chartObj.Chart.HasTitle = True
    chartObj.Chart.chartTitle.Text = chartTitle
    
    ' Add series to the chart
    For w = 501 To drlr
        With chartObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            ' Set series name
            .Name = wsLookup.Cells(w, j).Value
            
            ' Set series values
            .Values = wsLookup.Range(wsLookup.Cells(w, k), wsLookup.Cells(w, l)).Value
            
            ' Set series color
            .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = seriesColors(w Mod 3)
            
            ' Show data labels
            .ApplyDataLabels
        End With
    Next w
    
    ' Show data labels for each series
    For Each s In chartObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
        s.ApplyDataLabels
    Next s
    
    ' Display chart
    chartObj.Visible = True
    
    ' Increment the top position for the next chart
    lastChartTop = lastChartTop + 800
    
    ' Increment column indices for the next engineer
    p = p + 4
    j = j + 4
    k = k + 4
    l = l + 4
Next engCell

End Sub

Could we see the code you've tried please?

Also your two charts illustrate perfectly why 3D charts shouldn't be used - the one on the left looks like it's 2.5 as that's where the front of the 3D bit is, the one on the right looks like it's 100 as that's where the back of the 3D bit is.
